# Set custom thumbnail via YoutubeAPI doesn't work. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: api, youtube

I try to upload custom thumbnail for video.

Official documentation link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

Used scopes for requested access token was:
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https*://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload

Then i get response:

Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=my_video_id&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=my_upload_id: (403) The authenticated user doesnt have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails.

I set all needed scopes and still have not permissions. How can i resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: how we can verify this using youtube api that a user has a verified account so that he can upload customised thumbnails.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem. Found the solution:

Please verify your account by putting telephone number and enable "customised thumbnails" in your account's panel.

Docs: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431

Comment: how we can verify this using youtube api that a user has a verified account so that he can upload customised thumbnails.?

Comment: I used try-catch for that. If we catch SDK exception while uploading thumbnail - then it's not verified

Comment: I think it's possible, that the cause of exception throwing could be different. As far as I remember exception message in this case is not helpfull, when one want to know exact reason of failure.

Comment: Here is the error message: "The authenticated user doesn't have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails."