# Why the following error with a Brand Account : The authenticated user does'nt have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails

Tags: youtube-data-api

I just created a YouTube Brand Account to have a dedicated YouTube Channel.

I use the Data API to upload video and thumbnail.

The upload of the video works, but not the thumbnail one.

I have the following error : "The authenticated user doesnt have permissions to upload and set custom video thumbnails"

What is strange from my point of view, is that with the 'normal' YouTube account, I do not have this issue.

So is it possible possible the issue comes from the fact I use a YouTube Brand Account?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution thanks to another post:
[Set custom thumbnail via YoutubeAPI doesn't work. Can someone tell me why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636310/set-custom-thumbnail-via-youtubeapi-doesnt-work-can-someone-tell-me-why)

It is in fact necessary to 'validate' your account. For that Google sends you a SMS with a code.